# how I can show json data in tableviewcells in swift

Tags: ios, swift

> I want to show data in table cells 
>   now I want show data from api to table cell view on the screen

The output of this api link which is showing in console:

[image]

> this is struct variable

```
struct Team: Codable{ //here is struct veriables
var api_id: Int
var id: Int
var first_team:Int
var second_team:Int
var date: String  }
```

> here is Im getting data from api

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/matches") else {return}  
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
            error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                return }
        do {
            //here dataResponse received from a network request
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let model = try decoder.decode([Team].self, from:
                dataResponse) //Decode JSON Response Data
            print(model)


        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

> here is want to use data and show on screen

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TeamCell", for: indexPath) as! TeamTableViewCell
    //I want to show here data 
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Are you able to parse the response ?

Comment: You can do it like `cell.yourLbl.text = model[indexPath.row].propertyYouWantToShow` and you need to create `model` outside of function but inside the class.

Comment: my response showing in console but I want to show in tableview cells

Comment: @Tahir can you show your response sample here?

Comment: @Shezad https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4YKW.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global variable for storing teams

```
var teams = [Team]()
```

Replace

```
let model = try decoder.decode([Team].self, from:
                dataResponse) //Decode JSON Response Data
```

with

```
teams = try decoder.decode([Team].self, from:
                dataResponse) //Decode JSON Response Data

tableView.reloadData()
```

And then,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  teams.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TeamCell", for: 
    indexPath) as! TeamTableViewCell
    if let team = teams[indexPath.row] {
        cell.firstTeamLabel.text = "\(team.first_team)"
        cell.dateLabel.text = team.date
        ...
        // Note: Replace label names with your actual one.
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: @Tahir, it w'd be better if you go through tutorials if you are a beginner. There are plenty of them available online.

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'Team?' to type '[Team]?'

Comment: Please don't declare a data source array of a concrete table view as optional, declare it as empty array `var teams = [Team]()`. This avoids a lot of unnecessary question marks and optional bindings

Comment: thank you with some other changing my problem is solved 
this code very helpful